# predict.glmer on training set differs with and without newdata

Tags: r, lme4

This may be more of a bug report than a question, but: why does explicitly using the `newdata` argument to predict using the same dataset as the training data sometimes produce different predictions than omitting the `newdata` argument and using the training dataset explicitly?

```
library(lme4)
packageVersion("lme4") # 1.1.8
m1 <- glmer(myformula, data=X, family="binomial")
p1 <- predict(m1, type="response")
p2 <- predict(m1, type="response", newdata=X)
all(p1==p2) # FALSE
```

This isn't just a rounding error. I'm seeing `cor(p1,p2)` return 0.8.

This seems to be isolated to models with slopes. In the following plot, *implicit* means `predict(..., type="response")` without newdata, and *explicit* means `predict(..., type="response", newdata=X)`, where X is the same as training. The only difference between model 1 and the other models is that model 1 contains only (random) intercepts, and the other models have random intercepts and random slopes.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data such that we can also run the code to verify. Be sure to include how you specified the formula.

Comment: @MrFlick; try with `m1 <-   lmer(Reaction ~   Days +   (Days||Subject), sleepstudy)`

Comment: Hmm,  predictions are equal using `newX` rather than `newdata`

Comment: @user20650 you're right! newX does the trick. For those playing at home, try `?lme4::predict.merMod`. But why does `lme4::predict.merMod` treat `newdata` and `newX` differently?

Comment: Oh no. `lme4::predict.merMod` declares `newX` as a parameter... and NEVER uses it. So `newX` is the same as omitting `newdata`, but not because it uses `newX differently! If you specify `newX` and not `newdata`, then that omits `newdata`, and it's the same as my "implicit" case. @BenBolker, could you help?

Comment: FWIW, with lme4 1.1-7 (on linux, R 3.1.1 yep, a little out of date now) the **sleepstudy** example does return `TRUE` for `all(p1 == p2)`.

Comment: OK, the `newX` thing is certainly a mistake (probably something I was starting to implement that escaped).  But so far I don't have a reproducible example (because the `sleepstudy` example does work -- on 1.1-8 as well as 1.1-7).  I don't doubt that there's a bug in predict.merMod somewhere, but I will really need an example to use for debugging.

Comment: PS haven't checked a `glmer` example because I don't have a random-slopes GLMM model handy -- I doubt that `glmer`/`lmer` is the difference though.

Comment: @BenBolker and Gavin, thanks for the answer; but a little strange  - as with the OP, the predictions for the `sleepstudy` model aren't equal for me on ubuntu 12.04, R3.1.2, lme4 1.1.7.   Just to check, is this the right commands `m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days||Subject), sleepstudy);
p1 <- predict(m1, type="response");
p2 <- predict(m1, type="response", newdata=sleepstudy)`

Comment: @BenBolker I confirm that the `sleepstudy` example fails for me, exactly as for @user20650 ^^. I'm on Windows 7 x64, R 3.1.2, lme4 1.1.8.

Comment: conversation continued at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/279 .  I'm having a hard time thinking of what could differ among these platforms (FWIW, I'm not aware offhand of any changes in the predict method between 1.1-7 and 1.1-8 ...)

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that this is a bug in `predict.merMod` that has been fixed in the development version (in November 2014, as [this Github issue](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/257)).  If you have compilation tools installed you can install the development version directly from Github via

```
devtools::install_github("lme4/lme4")
```